# Merging two tables and calculating weighted sum in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all

I have the following two tables:

Table1

```
 shopid  hour      category  amount
    ------------------------------------
    1        7          food       10
    1        8          food       15
    1        10         misc.      5
    ...................................
```

Table2

```
 shopid  hour      category  amount
    ------------------------------------
    1        7          food       30
    1        8          food       10
    1        9          misc.      10
    ...................................
```

Now, I want to merge the two tables based on their shopid, event_hour and category. But want to calculate the weighted sum on the amount. The condition is, if I have the same shopid, hour, category then it will perform the weighted sum. Otherwise, it will keep the original data from table1 and table2. After the merging, the table would look like this:

MergedTable

```
shopid  hour      category  amount
------------------------------------
1        7          food       25   //amount= table1.amount*0.25+ table2.amount*0.75
1        8          food       11.25 //amount= table1.amount*0.25+ table2.amount*0.75
1        9          misc.      10   //this amount remains same as at hour 9 nothing was on table1.
1        10         misc.      5    //this amount remains same as at hour 10 nothing was on table2.
...................................
```

Any clue how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  You seem to want a `full join` and arithmetic:

```
select shopid, hour, category,
       (case when t1.shopid is null then t2.amount
             when t2.shopid is null then t1.amount
             else t1.amount * 0.25 + t2.amount * 0.75
        end) as weighted_sum
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (shopid, hour, category)
```